# Woocoommerce, применить купон через php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

подскажите пожалуйста есть купон, каким образом можно сделать его активацию вручную, через php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для применения купона нужно использовать метод [WC_Cart::apply_coupon](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Cart::apply_coupon)

Думаю лучше привязать его к событиям корзины и чекаута

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'addDiscount');
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'addDiscount');

function addDiscount() {
            if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
               return;
            }

            $coupon_code = 'COUPON';

            // add discount, if not added already
            if (!in_array($coupon_code, WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons())) {
                WC()->cart->apply_coupon($coupon_code);
            }
}
```

Comment: Сделал собственную функцию и вызываю ajax'ом через JS)